# Form Create View and 3 hierarchical models - Limit Choices for ForeignKey

Tags: django

I am trying to create an 'Expense Tracker'. I have query regarding create view and Models with 3 hierarchical levels. For eg:-

```
class ExpenseYear(models.Model):
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
 
class ExpenseMonth(models.Model):
    month = models.CharField(max_length = 14,blank = False)
    month_year = models.ForeignKey(ExpenseYear,related_name = 'month',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 
class Expenses(models.Model):
    expense = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    expense_month = models.ForeignKey(ExpenseMonth,related_name = 'expense', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now, while creating CreateView for 'Expenses' model, i am facing an issue. I want to display only the months in that particular year (in 'expense_month' foreignkey), but all months of all the years are being displayed in the 'expense_month' foreignkey.

This is what i am getting - [CreateView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKCSK.png)

I searched stackoverflow about limiting foreignkey choices and ended up finally with another code, but now no months are displayed in the foreign key

Forms.py

```
#forms.py
class ExpensesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Expenses
        fields = ('expenses','expense_month')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        month_year_id = kwargs.pop('month_year_id')
        super(ExpensesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['expense_month'].queryset = ExpenseMonth.objects.filter(month_year_id=month_year_id)
```

Views.py

```
#views.py
class ExpensesCreateView(CreateView):
    model = models.Expenses
    form_class = ExpensesForm
 
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ExpensesCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'month_year_id': self.kwargs.get('month_year_id')})
        return kwargs
```

However, as i said no months are displayed if i write this code.

This is what i am getting if i write the above code - [CreateView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZJ5g.jpg)

How to limit foreignkey choices? i checked Django Documentation, but i could find any particular answer for this. Can please Help me out. I have searched many questions related to this in stackoverflow and other websites. Can you please answer this question in this context itself (pls don't reply with a genenral code as, i am new to django and find it difficult to understand general answers)

Thanks in Advance !

Urls.py

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [         
path('year/<int:pk>/<int:pk2>/create_expense/',views.ExpensesCreateView.as_view(),name ='create_expense'),
]
```

Comment: Can you show the entry in `urls.py` for the ExpensesCreateView.

Comment: Yep, added urls.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the `get_form_kwargs` in your view:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(ExpensesCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'month_year_id': self.kwargs.get('month_year_id')})
    return kwargs
```

If you `print(self.kwargs.get('month_year_id'))` it will probably be `None`.

`self.kwargs` are the URL keyword arguments you provide to the view, in your case your url is providing two arguments `pk` and `pk2` here:

```
path('year/<int:pk>/<int:pk2>/create_expense/',views.ExpensesCreateView.as_view(),name ='create_expense'),
```

So you have two choices, either rename the argument in the path so it is `<int:month_year_id>` (I'm not sure whether you should rename pk or pk2 just from your code snippets).

**or**

In `get_form_kwargs` get either `pk` or `pk2` from `self.kwargs` instead of `month_year_id`, for example:

```
kwargs.update({'month_year_id': self.kwargs.get('pk2')})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now. But i don't understand why i have alter pk (the first primary key), though the 'Expenses' model depend on pk2 (the second primary key). What could be the possible reason?

Anyways, it works now. Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: Another query again. How to write the Updateview and DeleteView for the same?

I tried writing it the usual way, but it is throwing a lot of errors. The mistake is probably on my side, but i don't know the correct way to write the code

Comment: The official docs arent the best, try looking at https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/ you will see there is a function called `get_object` which is checking `pk_url_kwarg` which defaults to `pk`. So by default an UpdateView will take the `pk` argument from the url path and try to find a model instance with that ID - if you name the url argument something else like `pk2` you will either need to set `pk_url_kwargs` to `pk2` in the view, or define your own `get_object` function. Hope that helps.

Comment: That didn't work. Also, after trying out this, my now whole application is behaving weird. CreateView for Expenses works good, but the update and delete view for the 'month' model are not working. I don't know where i made mistake. Do you have any idea where the error might have been ?

Comment: Can you add your code for models, views, forms, urls and templates here https://codeshare.io/xv6yZj

Comment: Sure, but let me try to create the application and run it again. If it doesn't work i will add my code in there. I guess, the problem was that i had another model similar to this and django did all the entries in that model instead of the 'expenses' model. So i will re-run my program and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Hey! i re-run the application. Everything is working fine except the UpdateView and DeleteView for the 'expense' model. I need some help there .Do You want me to share the following 

- all 3 models in my project
- forms ( i have only 1 form)
- views.py ( all views ?)
- urls.py ( all urls ?)
- by relevant templates do you mean the templates of 'expense' model

.Or shall i just share the entire project ?